# What is the selection algorithm in f-16 stick LVDT?

Tags: flight-controls, f-16, flight-data-monitoring

In a reference:
https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88102main_H-1344.pdf
page 67 (71 of pdf file) in Table 12,[image]

it is said that the signal selection algorithm from the redundant LVDT of stick in f-16 is GCAF which means good channel average plus monitoring for a fourth input. What does this sentence exactly mean? I know the meaning of good channel average but what is the meaning of good channel average plus monitoring for a fourth input?